# Missing MP3 codec in Blender 2.79

Tags: audio, linux

I was using Blender 2.76 and was able to use mp3 codec as the audio output. Now in Blender 2.79 it did not want to render in mp3 for lack of codec. In my understanding it only accepted mpeg2 in the audio output. Is version 2.76 more complete in terms of output options? Or is it because I changed dristro from Ubuntu to Mint?

Comment: Try  sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Comment: "2.79 it did not want to render in mp3 for lack of codec." => did you get a specific error message? Please put it in your question (use the bottom 'edit' link). Or you just can't see the mp3 codec option, maybe?